# How do I create a near-real-time, scrolling line graph control in ASPX?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

How do I create a scrolling line graph in ASPX?

I have a data feed that is updated every few seconds and I'd like to graph that data and have the chart update automatically. The chart does not need to update in real-time, every 3-5 seconds, maybe even 10 seconds, is sufficient.

I'm not a hard-core web dev but my initial thoughts are to call the service, get the JSON data, and graph it. I'm not sure what out-of-the-box controls are available or how to go about implementing this.

I'm open to using a third party control, if it will make life easier. We have the DevExpress ASP.NET control suite.

Answer (score 1):

something like gRaphaël (http://g.raphaeljs.com/) & a json formatted feed should achieve what you're looking for. Telerik have a pure javascript graphing library that might help, but I can't remember what it's called right now.

Found it!  KendoUI http://www.kendoui.com/dataviz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put your chart control inside an updatepanel and can use timers to update it.
2. There is a very good java script base chart controls. Check [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DevExpress ASP.NET control suite, you can use the WebChartControl's built-in AJAX functionality. To update your chart you can send a callback to the server and generate the server-side [WebChartControl.CustomCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsWebWebChartControl_CustomCallbacktopic) event via the [ASPxClientWebChartControl.PerformCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsWebScriptsASPxClientWebChartControl_PerformCallbacktopic.aspx) client-side method.
This way, you should be able to asynchronously fetch data at server-side using the AJAX-based callback technology an easily implement your own scrolling line graph.
For an example, see the ["Highlighted Features - Gantt"](http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraChartsDemos/AdvancedViewTypes/GanttSeries.aspx) ChartsWebDemo module, illustrating this approach in action. Anyway please contact a [DevExpress Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) if you are run into a problem when using this approach. They will be happy to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ajax example for [Highcharts.Net](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/79560) in the [sample project](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). It does exactly what you are looking to achieve, without you writing a single line of javascript (purely C#)

See also : [Live example](http://highcharts.paulovich.com.br/Sample08.aspx)